# executing warnings in hadoop on windows

Tags: hadoop

I run the following command, but some warnings are occurred. How to solve these warnings.

```
C:\Users\Sunny's>hdfs dfs -mkdir /ram
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.6.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java 9/10 and install Java 8. Most of the Hadoop ecosystem does not support Java newer than 8.

[Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: According to what says this isn't Java 8?